# Controlling two DC motors with arduino uno

Tags: arduino, motordriver

So Im using this sample code to run my two motors...but the code only works for one motor...how do I modify this code for the other motor to work?  I tried replacing channel a with channel b but that didnt work for some reason?

```
const int channel_a_enable  = 6;
const int channel_a_input_1 = 4;
const int channel_a_input_2 = 7;
const int channel_b_enable  = 5;
const int channel_b_input_3 = 3;
const int channel_b_input_4 = 2;

void setup()
{
  pinMode( channel_a_enable, OUTPUT );  // Channel A enable
  pinMode( channel_a_input_1, OUTPUT ); // Channel A input 1
  pinMode( channel_a_input_2, OUTPUT ); // Channel A input 2

  pinMode( channel_b_enable, OUTPUT );  // Channel B enable
  pinMode( channel_b_input_3, OUTPUT ); // Channel B input 3
  pinMode( channel_b_input_4, OUTPUT ); // Channel B input 4

  Serial.begin( 38400 );
  Serial.println("Starting up");
}

void loop()
{
      Serial.println("Channel A forward");
      analogWrite( channel_a_enable, 255);
      digitalWrite( channel_a_input_1, HIGH);
      digitalWrite( channel_a_input_2, LOW);
      delay(5000);
      allInputsOff();

      Serial.println("Channel A reverse");
      analogWrite( channel_a_enable, 255);
      digitalWrite( channel_a_input_1, LOW);
      digitalWrite( channel_a_input_2, HIGH);
      delay(5000);
      allInputsOff();

      Serial.println("Channel A forward half speed");
      analogWrite( channel_a_enable, 127);
      digitalWrite( channel_a_input_1, HIGH);
      digitalWrite( channel_a_input_2, LOW);
      delay(5000);
      allInputsOff();
}

void allInputsOff()
{
  digitalWrite( 4, LOW );
  digitalWrite( 7, LOW );
  digitalWrite( 6, LOW );
  digitalWrite( 3, LOW );
  digitalWrite( 2, LOW );
  digitalWrite( 5, LOW );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your demo code references only channel 'a' except for set-up.

Here's a snippet showing how you'd turn both motors on:

```
Serial.println("Channels A and B forward");
analogWrite( channel_a_enable, 255);
digitalWrite( channel_a_input_1, HIGH);
digitalWrite( channel_a_input_2, LOW);
analogWrite( channel_b_enable, 255);
digitalWrite( channel_b_input_3, HIGH);
digitalWrite( channel_b_input_4, LOW);
delay(5000);
allInputsOff();
```

Of course the code for each motor is almost identical so you could create a subroutine:

```
void runMotor(int enablePin, int input1, int input2) {
    analogWrite( enablePin, 255);
    digitalWrite( input1, HIGH);
    digitalWrite( input2, LOW);
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
Serial.println("Channels A and B forward");
runMotor(channel_a_enable, channel_a_input_1, channel_a_input_2);
runMotor(channel_b_enable, channel_b_input_3, channel_b_input_4);
delay(5000);
allInputsOff();
```

Disclaimer: I'm writing this in my lunch break and not in the Arduino IDE so there may be minor errors.

Comment: Hi Phil, I did do that but this time only the motor connected to channel B worked, how do I change it so that both of them run? thanks again

Comment: The code you used is designed to run only one motor. To run two you need two sets of code. One for 'A' and one for 'B'. I'll edit my answer to show you one possible solution.

Comment: Hi Phil, I might be typing the code wrong...I'm not sure what you mean by a subroutine...:<

Comment: It looks like you are new to writing software, you need the basics under your belt before you jump into writing code for embedded systems - even though Arduino is simple, the programming approach requires a degree of prior knowledge of writing software. I recommend finding some tutorials on C or C++, the Arduino programming language appears to be a cut-down version of C++, I don't know C++ but my C knowledge has been sufficient.